# In JMS is it good to use same queue as a request as well as a reply queue?

Tags: queue, jms, message-queue

In JMS is it good to use same queue as a request as well as a reply queue? Is there any disadvantage or problem in doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

It's best, generally speaking, not to do this for the simple reason that you would need to use selectors to avoid retrieving request messages when you want responses, and vice versa.

It would be simpler to just have 2 separate queues, all other considerations being equal. I mean, you're not paying by the queue, right ?